Weird "dents" in mesh
A model I'm working with has these weird dark spots in certain places. I've tried methods from recalcuting normals to sculpting with the smooth brush, but nothing makes it go away.
Here's an image of what I'm talking about:


There is no image.

Maybe try Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

@moonboots That worked. Thanks

You have a problem of split normals (the normals that determine the shading). To fix it, go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > and click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data.
